# How to Close the menu after click on menu item

Tags: mobile, menu

I have a menu on website. Below is the HTML code.

```
<header class="navbar navbar-sticky navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark">
        <div class="container position-relative">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="./index.html">
                <img class="navbar-brand-regular" src="logo.png"/>
                <img class="navbar-brand-sticky" src="logo.png"/>
            </a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler d-lg-none" type="button" data-toggle="navbarToggler" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

            <div class="navbar-inner">
                <!--  Mobile Menu Toggler -->
                <button class="navbar-toggler d-lg-none" type="button" data-toggle="navbarToggler" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
               <nav>
                    <ul class="navbar-nav" id="navbar-nav">                            
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link scroll" href="#home">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link scroll" href="#about">About</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
```

On Mobile menu, when i click on a menu item, the menu did not closed. Below is the script code.
Did I miss anything?

```
// MAIN MENU TOGGLER ICON (MOBILE SITE ONLY)
    $('[data-toggle="navbarToggler"]').click(function () {
        $('.navbar').toggleClass('active');
        $('body').toggleClass('canvas-open');
    });
    // MAIN MENU TOGGLER ICON
    $('.navbar-toggler').click(function () {
        $('.navbar-toggler-icon').toggleClass('active');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap will handle all toggle/collapse by itself you do not need to write extra JS. Toggle button must not duplicate as you did to avoid messing up the navbar functioning.

Below is the answer. I optimized your params in few places. If my answer works for you, please tick it as final answer and upvote it so other people with same problem will get help too. Cheers

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark navbar-expand-sm fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Navbar">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
           <a class="navbar-brand mr-auto" href="./index.html"> <img src="#" height="#" width="#"> </a> 
           <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="Navbar">
               <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                    <li class="navbar-item active"><a class="nav-link" href="./index.html"> Home</a></li>
                    <li class="navbar-item"><a class="nav-link" href="./aboutus.html">About</a></li>                   
                </ul>               
            </div>
        </div>         
 </nav>
```